# Пользовательский интерфейс для загрузчика файлов

Tags: html

Как убрать стандартную надпись с именем файла (либо "файл не выбран") + кнопка "выбрать файл", на что-нибудь своё? Использую < form > и < input type = "file" >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Засунуть в контейнер с overflow:hidden, задать font-size по высоте контейнера, opacity в 0, а в самом контейнере - ваша кнопка "загрузить". Разумеется, также пригодится немного js для отображения имени файла.
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: Спасибо! Это то, что мне нужно!